# How do I add a button or context menu option for clearing recently viewed files?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Delete entire history of the dash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86544/delete-entire-history-of-the-dash)

I really miss the function from 10.04 where I easily could delete my recently viewed files by a mouse-click. Is it possible to get this feature in Ubuntu 11.04? For example, by adding a right-click function or a simple button on the top right of the recent-list saying "Empty"?

Comment: Hello Tomtom, Askubuntu is a Q&A site, not a rant or feature request board. I assumed that you're using Ubuntu 11.04 now and made the question less of a rant.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember Rick Spencer telling me he had written or was writing such an indicator. As I understood it, it would provide much the same functionality that you have in Firefox. That is to say, you would be able to deactivate logging or delete recent logs. I haven't tried it myself, but you can probably find it in his ppa on launchpad.