# How to make zeitgeist just log my application not my files

Tags: unity, unity-dash, zeitgeist

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with unity. I want to config the zeitgeist to just track my application but ignore the usage of files.
I tried to add "/" to the blacklist, but it didn't work. The recent files still appear in dash.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just adding / to the blacklist won't help as the already logged files will still appear in the dash. So, you would have to delete the current existing history from Privacy options in gnome-control-center.

- [How do I delete the entire history (Recently Used Items) in the dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86544/how-do-i-delete-the-entire-history-recently-used-items-in-the-dash)

---

And, by default, Unity uses locate for searching for matching files. As such, these files can still show up if you only blacklist logging of files.

To disable locate, run this command in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.FilesLens use-locate false
```