# How to turn off dash history from previous searches in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, unity-dash, privacy

Due to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1309751):

I'd like to have dash forget what I searched previously so future searches are not problematic. This would make Unity more consistent with retrieving the items I am telling it to. Is there any way to do this? I tried to toggle off the "history" in system settings >> privacy, but it did nothing...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete the entire history (Recently Used Items) in the dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86544/how-do-i-delete-the-entire-history-recently-used-items-in-the-dash)

Answer (score 2):

You were looking in the right place.  Go to 'Security & Privacy' and go to the 'Files & Applications' tab.  Toggle off 'Record file and application usage'.  Also be sure to click 'Clear Usage Data' to clear anything that is already cached.