# How can I disable the dash "Run" command history in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

Recently my computer has started executing the first item in my "Run" (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>) history, instead of executing what I type.  For example, I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type "thunderbird" and it opens **gnome-calc** because that is the first item in the history.  I would prefer to simply stop keeping a history at all, as it is only clutter to me.

If there is no way to prevent Ubuntu from keeping a run history, I would at least like it to execute the command that I type, instead of the first item in the history.

I have searched the internet and found answers which only seem to apply to older versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: @George Does that work for the history of commands run *from the desktop* in the dialog raised by pressing Alt+F2? If so, I recommend posting an answer. *user644407*: Since you've found some answers that didn't seem right for your system, can you [edit] your post to tell us what they were and exactly what happened when you tried them (or, if you decided not to because they seemed inapplicable to your system, why they were inapplicable)? That way, people won't have to reinvent the wheel -- the research you've done so far can be the starting point for people trying to help you find an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete the entire history (Recently Used Items) in the dash?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/86544/how-do-i-delete-the-entire-history-recently-used-items-in-the-dash)

Comment: @George Recently Used items are different from the Run dialog. I've dealt with recently used information in my own scripts and answers, and can tell that the suggested duplicate doesn't fit this question

Answer (score 1):

Simple, either directly in dconf-editor as in below screenshot (click on set to default after highlighting)  or in terminal,

`gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Runner history []`

A log out/in  will reflect the stored history being cleared

[image]

Comment: This suggestion will clear the existing history, but it will not disable the history entirely.  Is it not possible to stop Ubuntu from keeping a run history?